# AndEngine latest Library GLES2-AnchorCenter

Tags: android, andengine

I need latest AndEngine library **GLES2-AnchorCenter**.
please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Google is your friend - I searched for "AndEngine Github" - this is the first hit

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter